# Check if there is a BroadCastReceiver registered with action string

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

So I need a way to find out if there is a broadCastReceiver registered for a specific action string.

So to check if intent is available we have method (from
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

```
public boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   if (resolveInfo.size() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
   return false;
}
```

Which works but from my tests looks only for intents that activities are registered to. I have a broadCastReceiver registered for a specific action string. and it never sees it as registered. But if I fire broadcast. broadcast reacts. So method don't work in this case.

Ideas?

Answer (score 10):

It's almost the same, for broadcast receivers you should call [`PackageManager#queryBroadcastReceivers`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

```
public abstract List<ResolveInfo> queryBroadcastReceivers (Intent intent, int flags)

Since: API Level 1
Retrieve all receivers that can handle a broadcast of the given intent.

Parameters
intent  The desired intent as per resolveActivity().
flags   Additional option flags.

Returns
A List<ResolveInfo> containing one entry for each matching Receiver. These are ordered from first to last in priority. If there are no matching receivers, an empty list is returned.
```

Look at the docs, to see what else can you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    if (sendBroadcastReceiver != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    sendBroadcastReceiver = null;
}
```